# If they were freely available, what would be potential applications of the magnetic monopole?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-monopoles, applied-physics, dirac-monopole

viz.,  if the magnetic monopole (the hypothetical fundamental particle, not the fauxmonopole behavior in BECs) was discovered, and then found to be abundant or easily produced, what could they be used for?

Comment: according to a plasma physics prof I had in the 1970's, monopoles would be useful for confining plasmas for fusion reactors, but he did not explain why.

Comment: Welcome to PSE. IMO, this  a type of list question, and you might be better asking it based a more specific topic/application. The hypothetical nature of it may not help either, I am sorry to say, but see what the concensus view is.